# Browser gives div irrelevant height

Tags: php, css

I'm writing [a php page](http://tallinn.yhistransport.eu/test/kaart/) that shows a large image (7386x5186px) composed of smaller tiles. There are 25 rows and 25 columns of tiles. Each row is a `div.tileRow` and all tiles are `div.tile`s.

Majority of the tiles have a height of 208px, yet in Chrome `.tileRow` is 212px high, in FF it's 213px. Last row's tiles are 194px high, that's why I don't want to give `.tileRow` a fixed height. I tried the Inspect Element tool, but it doesn't say where the height comes from.

```
<div id="mapContents">
    <?php 
    for ($i = 1; $i < 26; $i++) {
        echo "<div class='tileRow'>";
        for ($j = 1; $j < 26; $j++) {
            $imagedir = $basedir . "kaart/tiles/kaart_" . $i . "_" . $j . ".png";
            $imagesize = getimagesize($imagedir);
            echo "<div class='tile' style=\"background-image: url('". $imagedir . "'); width: ".$imagesize[0]."px; height: ".$imagesize[1]."px;\"></div>";
            //echo "<div id='tile_".$i."_".$j."' class='mapTile'></div>";
        }
        echo "</div>";
    }
    ?>
</div>

.tileRow {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.tile {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Margins and paddings should be neutralized, which is why I can't figure out what causes this.

Comment: See: http://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block

Comment: Check other properties: Have you line-height or similar set? Look at values in the computed tab of F12. Sounds like there is something calculated in ems or similar that are rounded differently in different browsers.... or look at Diodeus' comment above ;)

Comment: Try floating the divs instead of displaying them inline block

Comment: Setting the `.tileRow` font-size to 0px did the trick, thanks, Diodeus!